# How to set inline SVG to stretch with CSS using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I usually use:

```
<style>
svg
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

To set an inline svg such as:

```
<svg>
    Content ...
</svg>
```

To stretch and cover the screen. I am using transforms to scale the image in and out similar to browser zoom. The problem occurs when I soom out the image because it is not in the centre or stretched anymore. This is because I use:

```
var documentX = $(document).width();
var documentY = $(document).height();

offsetX = (documentX / 2) - window.x;
offsetY = (documentY / 2) - window.y;

$("svg").offset({top:offsetY,left:offsetX});
```

To shift the image and then zoom in based on where on the image the user clicks. As stated once I zoom out I need the image to return to the way it was initially. I hope that made sense ...

I would prefer a jQuery solution however a JavaScript solution will also be fine if no such jQuery solution exists. I have tried:

```
$("svg").css({"height":"100%","width":"100%"});
```

With no success. This is my HTML Head:

```
<head>
<title>Main</title>

<style>
svg
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        window.x = e.pageX;
        window.y = e.pageY;
    });
</script>

<script>
    function init()
    {
        window.zoom = 1;
        window.isZoomed = 0;
        window.zoomScale = 3;
    }

    function scale()
    {           
        if (window.isZoomed == 0)
        {
            var documentX = $(document).width();
            var documentY = $(document).height();

            offsetX = (documentX / 2) - window.x;
            offsetY = (documentY / 2) - window.y;

            $("svg").offset({top:offsetY,left:offsetX})

            document.body.style.msTransform = "scale(" + (window.zoom * window.zoomScale) + ")";
            window.zoom = window.zoom * window.zoomScale;
            window.isZoomed = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            document.body.style.msTransform = "scale(" + (window.zoom / window.zoomScale) + ")";
            window.zoom = window.zoom / window.zoomScale;
            window.isZoomed = 0;

            <!-- Need to stretch to fit window here -->
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

I basically need to do this

```
svg
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But in JavaScript/jQuery ???

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript, so long as your SVG has a [`viewbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute, you can just use CSS. As you can see in the following example, there is a `viewbox` of 200 by 200, but it is filling a div that it 400px/400px.

**Example:**

```css
.wrap {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
.wrap svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 200 200">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150" rx="20" style="fill:#ff0000;" />
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="150" height="150" rx="40" style="fill:#0000ff; fill-opacity:0.7;" />
  </svg>  
</div>
```

If needed, you can set the `viewbox` in jQuery like this (obviousness substituting the dimensions as needed).

```
$('svg')[0].setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 200 200');
```

Comment: Should be `viewBox` (the html parser automatically adjusts the casing when parsing, but the attr setter doesn't AFAIK).

Comment: @ErikDahlström I didn't have any problem with it in testing. I think you may be thinking of the behavior of `.prop`?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/7u5m9vv2/, looks like the attr setter sets something in the jQuery internal state, but it has no effect on rendering. Using standard DOM `setAttribute` does work however.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Oh yeah, I forgot about that. jQuery doesn't work very well for SVG DOM manipulation.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thank you for your reply. I already know how to make it fill the browser window with CSS. I have done that initially however I need to do it with javascript/jQuery since I scale the image in and out. I have Edited my question to include my HTML Head.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry I solved it. Just decided to use

```
location.reload()
```

which works for me ...